# Adding a PHP Prepared statement to a SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a Prepared statement and incorporate it into a SELECT statement, as shown below. I am happy with creating the Prepared statement for line 1, but I need to include the result in the SELECT statement in line 2 as I cannot use the WHERE option because of line 4 (function of a search)
So, I guess I need some insight into how I can combine both the SELECT and prepared statement into line 2.

```
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm WHERE sales_agent = '".$username."'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm";
$query = isset($_GET['query'])?('%'.$_GET['query'].'%'):'%';
$sql .= "WHERE company_name LIKE :query OR email LIKE :query OR 
    date_followup LIKE :query "; //is needed for a search function
$start = (($paginator->getCurrentPage()-1)*$paginator->itemsPerPage);
$length = ($paginator->itemsPerPage);
$sql .= "ORDER BY date_followup DESC limit :start, :length ";

$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':start',$start,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':length',$length,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':query',$query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();


foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row1)
```

Comment: `// WHERE sales_agent = '".$username."'` That will comment everything form beyond that poin in the sql query. So the only thing you are executing is `SELECT * FROM customer_crm;`

Comment: `//` isn't a comment prefix in MySQL.

Comment: Correct, I just left the comment in so that it is easier to see what I meant, so please ignore the comment. The whole line(minus the //) would be the prepared statement.

Comment: In the current code, your probably missing a space when you add the `$sql .= "WHERE` clause. `$sql .= " WHERE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two `WHERE` clauses. The second one should be `AND` to combine those conditions into the query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm WHERE sales_agent = :username";
$query = isset($_GET['query'])?('%'.$_GET['query'].'%'):'%';
$sql .= " AND (company_name LIKE :query OR email LIKE :query OR 
    date_followup LIKE :query)"; //is needed for a search function
$start = (($paginator->getCurrentPage()-1)*$paginator->itemsPerPage);
$length = ($paginator->itemsPerPage);
$sql .= " ORDER BY date_followup DESC limit :start, :length ";

$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':start',$start,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':length',$length,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':query',$query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: I was writing the same.. I'd just move also the $query, $start and $lenght  part after and keep the $sql in one piece only. I don't see the reason to keep it splitted.